# Return Values for partially matched string characters

Tags: r, grepl

I have two data frames as

```
> df1
      A            B
1MG               70
ABOF              52  
Amazon            12
American Swan     10
Clovia            12


> df2

      A                            B                                         
1 MG Solution
ABOF Prime
Dual Command
Amazon AWF
American Swan Financial Services 
Clovia World Spaces
Shape Makers 
Unions
```

I want to return values for partially matched characters from `df1` to `df2`. For example , Amazon has value 12 in `df1` and in `df2` i want this value to be returned in front of every string that has Amazon in it. If not found return `NA`.

`result_df` is the expected output i am expecting .

```
> reslut_df

      A                             B                      
1 MG Solution                       70
ABOF Prime                          52
Dual Command                        NA
Amazon AWF                          12
American Swan Financial Services    10
Clovia World Spaces                 12 
Shape Makers                        NA
Unions                              NA
```

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165256/r-merge-data-frames-allow-inexact-id-matching-e-g-with-additional-characters).

Comment: Is there any simpler way than this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165256/r-merge-data-frames-allow-inexact-id-matching-e-g-with-additional-characters

Comment: The link you quoted looks fairly close to your problem.  Try it, it is easier than you might think.